# FxCOp Custom Rules

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have been working on FxCOP Custom rules. I am working on getting lines of IL instructions used. I have a basic doubt, when we implement a c# code, we get opcodes, are these in different lines for every instruction(Source code Instruction has multiple opcodes in one line)

now, my mentor is asking me to count different lines in which multiple opcodes have been employed. However, I am of the understanding, that each IL instruction is in a different line. I will try to show the difference in opinion as follows:

Source code

```
opcode 1, opcode 2, opcode 3
opcode 4, opcode 5

My Opinion                   My Mentor's Opinion

Opcode 1                     Opcode 1,Opcode 2, Opcode 3
Opcode 2                     Opcode 5, Opcode 6
opcode 3
```

I have not been able to find which is true. Please help me find if for any given c# code, IL instructions are in separate lines in spite of the instruction being in the same line for source code, or if it is what my mentor believes and there is a way of finding different lines.

Thanks

Comment: I don't comprehend what you are asking. A C# source line can be represented by 0...n IL opcodes. The line could be removed by the compiler (so 0 opcodes), or it could be x opcodes

Comment: yes we can get the total opcode counts, agreed. But can we get how many opcodes are employed in every line of source code. I think, we can't... But I want to confirm.

Comment: IL does not have "lines".  You'll need the PDB file to map IL opcodes back to source code lines.  Simplest way is by using ildasm.exe's /linenum option.  Do note that you are wasting your time on this, Roslyn is the future and it is here today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
{
    Method method = member as Method;

    if (method == null)
    {
        return base.Check(member);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Method: {0}", member.Name);

    InstructionCollection ops = method.Instructions;

    foreach (Instruction op in ops)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}, Line: {1}, Pos: {2}, OpCode: {3}", op.SourceContext.FileName, op.SourceContext.StartLine, op.SourceContext.StartColumn, op.OpCode);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return base.Problems;
}
```

Note that in Release mode the relationship between line of code and OpCodes is a little "random", because the C# compiler can rearrange a little the code. In Debug mode the relationship is much more clear.

Note (2) that I'm only considering `StartLine` and `StartColumn`. There are `EndLine` and `EndColumn` properties.

Comment: The end line and the end column properties are used in a similar fashion?

Comment: @shivangikulshrestha Yes. They are numbers. I haven't tested how they work with block instructions like `if (...) { ... some lines ... } else { ... some other lines }`

Comment: yes xanatos, with a slight change in logic I am able to use the above concept to my need. thank you :) and they are working fine for the block instructions as well.